# MATLAB : delete an element in a cell array in a for loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

How to delete an element in a cell array in a for loop? 
 l have a set called stated_n{i} where i varies from 1 to n (let n=5) for exemple :

```
stated_n{1} = {3,7,8,9,14,99} 
stated_n{2} = {14,8,19,104,98} 
stated_n{3} = {67,7,8,9,14,11} 
stated_n{4} = {41,76,8,18,14,56} 
stated_n{5} = {65,13,16,9,8,103}
```

l want for exemple to delete a value k (let k= 8)from each stated_n{i} how to do that to remove 8 from each stated_n (1:5)

```
for i=1:N 
    if ismember(k,stated_n{i})
       %remove k from stated_n{i}
       % update stated_n{i} and display it
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `find` and `cell2mat`.

The idea is to convert each cell to a numeric matrix and use `find` to find the index/indices where `k` occurs. Then delete those entries. That also works if there are more than 1 instances of `k`.

```
clear
clc

stated_n{1} = {3,7,8,9,14,99} ;
stated_n{2} = {14,8,19,104,98} ;
stated_n{3} = {67,7,8,9,14,11} ;
stated_n{4} = {41,76,8,18,14,56} ;
stated_n{5} = {65,13,16,9,8,103} ;

N = numel(stated_n);
k = 8;
for i=1:N 

    idx = find(cell2mat(stated_n{i}) == k);

    stated_n{i}(idx) = [];

   %// Display

   stated_n{i}
end
```

Output:

```
ans = 

    [3]    [7]    [9]    [14]    [99]


ans = 

    [14]    [19]    [104]    [98]


ans = 

    [67]    [7]    [9]    [14]    [11]


ans = 

    [41]    [76]    [18]    [14]    [56]


ans = 

    [65]    [13]    [16]    [9]    [103]
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: the check for emptiness is actually not needed; if the indexing variable is empty it's an automatic no-op.

Comment: mh so `neighbour_n` is not a cell then. What if you remove the call to `cell2mat` and afterward use regular matrix indexing?

Comment: it doesn't work in my case (in a for loop) .it returns me : 
??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
 Error in ==> cell2mat at 43 cellclass = class(c{1});
 Error in ==> broadcastelimination at 114 idx = find(cell2mat(neighbour_n{i}) == k);



N = numel(neighbour_n);
for k=1:N
            for i=1:N
                if (ismember(k, stated_n{i}));
          
                     idx = find(cell2mat(stated_n{i}) == k);
                      stated_n{i}(idx) = [];

                   
                end
end

Comment: how to do that benoit_11

Comment: Did you try the code I posted? Yours has 2 for-loops and one loop with `k` as loop increment which is conflicting with the use of `k` above. You don't need to use `ismember...` with the `find` function I use. See my comment above please; `neighbour_n` is not a cell

Answer (score 1):

To delete a single value:

```
k = 8;
result = cellfun(@(x) x([x{:}]~=k), stated_n, 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

To delete several values:

```
k = [8 4];
result = cellfun(@(x) x(~ismember([x{:}], k)), stated_n, 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Comment: in my case k is a set of value

Comment: Well, use second part of the answer then (and you should have specified that in your question)

Comment: It does work. Try `stated_n{1} = {3,7,8,9,14,99}; 
stated_n{2} = {14,8,19,104,98};` (taken from your question) and then apply second part of my answer `k = [8 4];
result = cellfun(@(x) x(~ismember([x{:}], k)), stated_n, 'uniformoutput', 0);`

Comment: No, sorry. I don't give my email in StackOverflow. Not just you; I just don't want to use my email for that

Comment: @pinkfloyd Did you paste the code _as is_ five comments above this?